# Recurse a limited amount of folders

Tags: powershell, recursion, ntfs

I have the following snippet of code from a script, used in order to get the NTFS permissions on file shares.

```
if ($ComputerName -eq '.'){
$Path = $Folder
}

else {
$Path = "\\$ComputerName\$Folder"
}ls

if ($OutputFile){
Get-Childitem $Path -Recurse:$Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName} | Select-Object @{Name="Path";Expression={$_.PSPath.Substring($_.PSPath.IndexOf(":")+2) }},@{Name="Type";Expression={$_.GetType()}},Owner -ExpandProperty Access | Export-CSV $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
}

else{
Get-Childitem $Path -Recurse:$Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName} | Select-Object @{Name="Path";Expression={$_.PSPath.Substring($_.PSPath.IndexOf(":")+2) }},@{Name="Type";Expression={$_.GetType()}},Owner -ExpandProperty Access | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

At the moment when I run this I am able to generate a report on the NTFS permissions, however I would like to make the code recurse one extra folder deeper in a file share. My problem however is I only know of methods to completely recurse through all folders or get the current folders in a path.

For example assume I had a folder called 'test' and inside of test there were two other folders called 'temp1' and 'temp2', with there being one more folder inside of temp2 called 'extra.' I'd want it to get the NTFS permissions for 'test' and then go one level farther and report permissions for 'temp1' and 'temp2,' but I would not want it to get 'extra.'

EDIT:

```
if ($OutputFile){
gci c:\|%{if($_.PSIsContainer){GCI $_.FullName|get-acl};$_|get-acl}|Select-Object @{Name="Path";Expression={$_.PSPath.Substring($_.PSPath.IndexOf(":")+2) }},@{Name="Type";Expression={$_.GetType()}},Owner -ExpandProperty Access | sort PSParentPath|Export-CSV $OutputFile -NoType
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually recurse 1 level easily enough. Try this on for size:

```
if ($ComputerName -eq '.'){
$Path = $Folder
}

else {
$Path = "\\$ComputerName\$Folder"
}ls

if ($OutputFile){
gci c:\|%{if($_.PSIsContainer){GCI $_.FullName|get-acl};$_|get-acl}|sort PSParentPath|Export-CSV $OutputFile -NoType
}

else{
gci c:\|%{if($_.PSIsContainer){GCI $_.FullName|get-acl};$_|get-acl}|sort PSParentPath|FT -Auto
}
```

Comment: just noticed that you posted this, need to be quicker next time :)

Comment: Quick question, I still want to keep parsing for the data that I was originally getting. I ended up using your code and added my select-object portion of the code. One thing I'm noticing however is that it seems as though I am checking the exact same path multiple times. Would you know why by any chance? I edited my original post to include the altered code

Comment: Move your Select comment to after the Sort. Because of the way we are recursing it feeds objects down the pipe all out of order, so it will give some objects from a folder, then some from another, then back to the first, and the Sort takes care of that. Your Select is filtering out the property that the Sort is working off of, so that broke it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will go down to a depth of one folder

```
Get-Childitem $path  | %{get-childitem -path $_.fullname}
```